# Flask-SQLAlchemy event listeners, unable to get old DB data before update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build an audit log mechanism in Flask-SQLAlchemy using the event.listens_for function.
I need to capture old DB row data before the new transaction is committed so I keep a log of the changes. I have tried all kind of ways, session events, mapper events.. I can't get the old row data from any of the objects in the event listener decorator.

Here's a quick example

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))


with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()


@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    # Get the original state of the user from the database
    original_user = User.query.get(target.id)

    # Record the original values
    original_name = original_user.name
    original_email = original_user.email

    # Log the changes
    print(f"Updating user: {original_name} ({original_email}) to {target.name} ({target.email})")


# Add new user
new_user = User(name="First_User", email="s@s.com")

with app.app_context():
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

# Update name on the existing user
with app.app_context():
    update_record = User.query.filter_by(name="First_User").first()
    update_record.name = "new_name"
    db.session.merge(update_record)
    db.session.commit()
```

Calling the existing DB entry by using the target.id inside of the decorator brings up a record that already has the new data.

Here is the output if you run the above code:
`Updating user: new_name (s@s.com) to new_name (s@s.com)`

I'm expecting:
`Updating user: "First_User" (s@s.com) to new_name (s@s.com)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the original values through the [history](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History) interface. The ORM tracks the state of each instrumented attribute between flushes, updating the history's `added` attribute with new values and storing the old values in its `deleted` attribute. This version of your listener:

```py
@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    # Attributes to track.
    tracked = dict.fromkeys(['name', 'email'])

    insp = db.inspect(target)
    for k in tracked:
        attr = getattr(insp.attrs, k)
        history = attr.history
        # If a scalar attribute has been changed, the old value will be in
        # deleted.
        if history.added:
            tracked[k] = history.deleted[-1]
        else:
            tracked[k] = attr.loaded_value
    # Log the changes
    print(
        f"Updating user: {tracked['name']} ({tracked['email']}) to {target.name} ({target.email})"
    )
```

outputs

```
Updating user: First_User (s@s.com) to new_name (s@s.com)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent 2 days on this and couldn't figure it out. Your code works perfectly.